# Is it allowed to preserve a body in a temple's premises?

Tags: temple, ramanujacharya, body, ranganatha

Ramanujacharya's body is preserved in Sri Rangam temple by mummification. Is it allowed as per agama or other shastra to bury/preserve a body inside a temple premises?

Comment: There are others that have had their bodies preserved. Sri Anandamayi Ma's body is kept in her temple in Kankhal. If convenient, sannyasins are not always burned, their bodies are often put directly into a river. They are considered to have 'burned' their bodies at the time of receiving sannyas.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda making individual temples are different thing ... this is a famous temple of vishnu which follows pancharatra agama.  but i  m talking about actual temples and associated rules.

Comment: The Srirangam temple is a complex of many areas which includes roads, shops, some houses etc. the body is nowhere near the sannidhi.

Comment: @user1952500 i have been to the temple what about you ?

Comment: Yes I have been there a few times.

Comment: @user1952500 then how come you are making such statements ? There are many small sannidhis in the prAkarams. So the moola sannidhi is not the only temple there. What about other temples ? How far are they from ramanuja.temple ?

Comment: I think Srirangam is a unique temple with sannidhis 100s of metres apart and society in between. If you have two temples close by with a 100m gap where a few streets pass, I don’t think you can consider the intermediate place as part of the temple and ensure no hearse vehicles pass on the road for example. You can’t say that there should be no women in the nearby homes in their cycles. That was my thought in saying it.

Comment: That said, I would also like to know the answer and have not rebuked the question. It was to add context to the temple which is unique (not like many other temples with vigrahas in a limited area). The concept of temple premises is different in this case.

Comment: Note that people do consecrate and use parts of dead animals in direct activities (skin, hair, tusks etc). Not exactly the same but there may be similar consecration methods in the same works.

Comment: @user1952500 but.such kind of.comments can be misleading. If there are minor temples near ramanuja sannidhi then also its a temple premise. Please don't compare shops with graveyards for heaven sake !!!

Comment: @RakeshJoshi the body is not near Ramanuja sannidhi, and is not publicly available for viewing. The question is misleading when it says temple premises as the body is not present there. And comparing it to a graveyard is exactly the point I want to rebuke.

Comment: @user1952500 you are presenting misleading facts here. Its available to public i myself had seen it. But if.its not body but a replica its fine. If real body then it raises many questions. Your point is that there are many shops etc. So.what has shops to.do with body ? This point is no good..

Comment: I did not know that. I had to go through multiple channels in order to see it. The point about shops is the following: it’s not a single temple complex. In temples for example, women in periods are not allowed. They are allowed in the shops. Similarly for urinals etc. if you have two temples 100m apart, will you consider all locations between the temples as part of the premises? I don’t think that’s a valid assumption. Srirangam is like a city of temples. All parts between the temples are not part of the premises.

Comment: @user1952500 better prove the points that urinals are not.allowed. next see my post on women menstruation. Thirdly no comparison between shops and urinals with body...

Comment: Well my thoughts are here. I have neither downvoted, nor spoken strongly against this issue. I will not spend much more time on this. The whole point hinges around what is considered as premises, and the consecration methods. It is not useful to make fun of a practice by mentioning ‘so-called saints’ until there is clear information. That is what I have tried to bring out.

Comment: Temple.prakaras are also having temples which are minor to the moola murti. Its better to continue this talk in chat room if you wish